# set groupt of radion value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a group ooa radion buttons defined as so

```
<input type="radio" name="required[status]" id="status" value="1">Yes </label>
<input type="radio" name="required[status]" id="status_1" value="0"> No </label>
<input type="radio" name="required[status]" id="status_2" value="2">Maybe </label>
```

this is stores the value `0,1,2` in a field status in the db

later, i get the value from db as 1, how do i use jquery to check the appropriate radio button?

Comment: What have you already tried? Where do you get stuck? Show some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to check the radio button element by its value you can you the jquery attribute selector.

[click me](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

you can get the element by its value like this:

```
$('[value=VALUE_FROM_DB]').prop("checked", true);
```